Why not alternate GtG and traditional workouts for a particular movement week-by-week?
Everything I've read about greasing the groove (GtG) says to do it 4-6 weeks straight, and to omit the muscle in question from any traditional workouts during that time. But if I want to maximize reps of a movement (say, pullups) for the long term, wouldn't I be better off alternating GtG and traditional hypertrophic workouts on a regular schedule, like, say, a week of GtG, a week of traditional, a week of GtG, etc.? What are the pros and cons of such a plan?

What do you mean by "maximize a movement for the long-term"?

@DavidScarlett I mean "maximize the number of reps I can do." E.g., I want to do as many pullups as possible, for the long term, not just six weeks from now and then see it taper off again if I stop GtG. I've edited the question to clarify.

If you read the post you linked in your question you'd know that greasing the groove will introduce a lot of fatigue, so you want to give your muscles the appropriate time to adapt and recover.
Alternating with hypertrophy would possibly leave you too fatigued to progress on either workouts.
After a few weeks the muscles (and tendons) will be adapted to the extra volume and you can re-introduce hypertrophy exercises.
You also don't need to omit the muscle entirely; for example if you're greasing for pull-ups you can still do rows, since it works the back muscles in a different plane. You just want to avoid too much fatigue on the target muscle with the same movement pattern during the first few weeks.

It sounds like they're asking about alternating between a week of GtG, then a week of regular hypertrophy training with no GtG, then a week of GtG, etc. Not doing both GtG and regular hypertrophy training at the same time.

@DavidScarlett indeed, edited.
